# Redirection with routes in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I am creating a redirection for an app written with .Net Framework 4.5.

In the RouteConfig file i create a new `routes.MapRoute()` and it works.
It shows the Controller and action that I want.

But I dont want to mantain the user the url and use the app from there.
I just want that when the user write /Something it redirects to /AnotherSomething, not to use the app in /Something.

How should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518935/mvc-redirect-to-default-route/11520787#11520787

Answer (score -1):

If understand you correctly:

```
routes.RouteMap("RedirectExample", "Something", new { controller : "MyController", action : "AnotherSomething"});
```

Comment: I think this show me the app  that I want but maintains the URL. I want that when the user types /Something it get redirects to Something/Anothersomething.