# MVC custom URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a route configured like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "TEST/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It works fine to redirect to respective controller and actions.

I want to add another redirection on TEST so that if somebody uses www.mysite.com/TEST, it should redirect www.mysite.com/Test/Home instead of giving 403- Forbidden: Access is denied error.

I'm trying like this but could not achieve it.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AnotherDefault",
                url: "TEST",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to redirect from www.mysite.com or www.mysite.com/TEST to www.mysite.com/TEST/Home

To add to the confusion, I also had a physical folder TEST in my application root.  Just wondering if keeping another web.config in there would solve? I tried but of no luck

Please advise what i'm missing here.  Thanks

After some experiment I have found that the physical folder TEST is causing redirection rule to fail.  I changed my route to TEST1 in URL instead of TEST, it worked.  But, I can't rename TEST folder.  Please advise

Comment: Have a look at the order in which these routes are added.

Comment: yes, i tried that too

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be because of physical folder TEST, I get 403 - Forbidden error

Comment: Perhaps remove the redundant default id from "AnotherDefault"? Do you have "RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);" in your Application_Start() in the Global.asax?

Comment: yes, I have it already in Global.asax; my routing works if I use www.mysite.com/TEST/mycontroller/myaction; but my only problem is i'm not able to redirect www.mysite.com/TEST to www.mysite.com/TEST/Home.  I have a physical folder also called TEST. I'm only worried if it is conflicting with my routing

Comment: rename the physical folder and give it a go. If not have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518935/mvc-redirect-to-default-route

Comment: Please see my updated question; Unfortunately, I can't rename the folder

Comment: do you mean to keep another copy of Global.asax inside that folder TEST?

Comment: @RenanAraújo I don't know why but I have tried it; still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the property RouteExistingFiles to true above the Route configurations

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "TEST/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

This should allow you to keep the name of folder and also the route name to be "TEST". Let me know how it works out for you

Comment: awesome!! this is what i'm looking for. thanks jonni

Comment: it created another problem... Can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832209/mvc-routeexistingfiles-issue?

Answer (score 0):

Keep using the first route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "TEST/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and add this in your Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: nope, still the same issue.  Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
We Can manage url routing by validate from database.
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 // here i pass my parameter like  wwww.abc.com/country-state-city 

        routes.MapLocalizedRoute("SeoFriendlyUrl",
        "{SeoFriendlyName}",
        new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" },
        new[] { "MigrationTest.Controllers" });
      // it is default 
        routes.MapRoute( name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

}

public static class LocalizedRouteExtensionMethod
{
    public static Route MapLocalizedRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces)
    {
        return MapLocalizedRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
    }
    public static Route MapLocalizedRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
    {
        if (routes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
        }
        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }

        var route = new clsRouteData(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
        };

        if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
        {
            route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
        }

        routes.Add(name, route);

        return route;
    }
}
public class clsRouteData : Route
{
    public clsRouteData(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler)
    {
    }
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData data = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (data != null)
        {
            var SeoFriendliyName = data.Values["SeoFriendlyName"] as string;

        if (SeoFriendliyName=="india-raj-jaipur")
            {
            data.Values["controller"] = "City";
            data.Values["action"] = "Index";
            // Can be send parameter
            //data.Values["Id"] = Resutls.Id;
            }

        }
  else
 {

data.Values["controller"] = "Norecord";
            data.Values["action"] = "Index";
            // Can be send parameter
            //data.Values["Id"] = Resutls.Id;
}
        return data;
    }

}
```